# How to prove this asymptotic formula:$J_n=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2+x^3)^ndx\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How to prove this asymptotic formula:$$J_n=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2+x^3)^ndx\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}$$
My idea is to solve this $J_n=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2+x^3)^ndx$ .Is it feasible to calculate its recursion formula or general term formula？Or maybe there is a relationship between $J_n=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2+x^3)^ndx$ and $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}$ which I need to find out?
Any idea is ok. This problem is important to me. I really need your help.Thank you very much.

Comment: $J_n = \int_0^1 \sum_{r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = n} C(n; r1, r2, r3) (-1)^{r_2} x^{2r_2 + 3r_3} dx$. You can integrate this term by term to get $J_n = \sum_{r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = n} C(n; r1, r2, r3) (-1)^{r_2} \frac{1}{2r_2 + 3r_3+1}$. Essentially you need to show this summation is $\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}$.

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic formula is true and you're just looking for a proof?  Or is this a conjectured asymptotic formula?

Comment: @Anon Thank you!I will try now!But I have a question.My school hasn't taught $C(n;r1,r2,r3)$,what is its name?What does it mean?It looks like permutation and combination,But I can't look it up on the Internet,please give me its name.Anyway,Thank you very much!

Comment: [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method?useskin=vector)

Comment: Its my school homework，it must be true.

Comment: $C(n; r1,r2,r3)$ is called multinomial coefficient; look up multinomial theorem. I think it still might be hard showing that sum is $\sim$ to RHS. @Sal's method to use Laplace method generates something an expression similar to the form of RHS but I can't figure out how to write the integrand as $e^{Mf(x)}$, Sal could you clarify?

Comment: The integrand is $( \dots)^n=e^{n\ln(\dots)}$, and we are seeking the $n\to\infty$ asymptotics. Show that the maxima of the integrand is at $x=0$, and argue that the contribution from the right endpoint is negligible. Then expand $\ln(\dots)$ around $x=0$ to second order and perform the Gaussian integral on $0<x<\infty$

Comment: Thank you Sal!This method is too advanced for me.I will try to understand and use it to solve this problem.Wait my good news.Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one can use [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) to determine the asymptotic of the integral, but some modifications are necessary because $F(x) = 1-x^2+x^3$ attains its maximum at both endpoints of the interval $[0, 1]$.

As a first step we estimate the contribution of the integral over $[1/3, 1]$: $F$ is *convex* on that interval, so that
$$
 0 \le F(x) \le \frac{1-x}{2/3}F(1/3) + \frac{x-1/3}{2/3} F(1) = \frac{x+8}{9}
$$
and therefore
$$
 \int_{1/3}^1 F(x)^n \, dx \le \int_{1/3}^1 \left(\frac{x+8}{9} \right)^n \, dx < \frac{9}{n+1} \, .
$$

Now we consider the function
$$
f(x) = \ln F(x) = \ln(1-x^2+x^3) \, .
$$
$f$ is $\le 0$ on $[0, 1]$, decreasing on $[0, 2/3]$, with $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, $f''(0) = -2$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. From the Taylor series of $f$ at $x=0$ it follows that there is a $\delta \in (0, 1/3)$ such that
$$
     (-1-\epsilon) x^2 \le f(x) \le (-1+\epsilon) x^2 
$$
for $0 \le x \le \delta$.

For an upper estimate of the integrals $J_n$ we have
$$
 J_n = \int_0^\delta F(x)^n \,  dx + \int_\delta^{1/3} F(x)^n \, dx +  \int_{1/3}^1 F(x)^n \, dx \\
 \le \int_0^\delta F(x)^n \,  dx + \frac 13 F(\delta)^n + \frac{9}{n+1}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\delta F(x)^n \, dx &\le \int_0^\delta e^{-n (1-\epsilon)x^2} \,  dx \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1-\epsilon)}} \int_0^\sqrt{n(1-\epsilon)} e^{-y^2} \, dy \\
 & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1-\epsilon)}} \int_0^\infty e^{-y^2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1-\epsilon)}} \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} \, .
\end{align}
$$
Combining these estimates we get
$$ \tag{*}
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n J_n \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}} \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}  \, .
$$

For a lower estimate of the integrals we write
$$
\begin{align}
 J_n & \ge \int_0^\delta e^{nf(x)} \,  dx \\
  &\ge \int_0^\delta e^{-n (1+\epsilon)x^2} \,  dx \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}} \int_0^\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)} e^{-y^2} \, dy \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}} \left (\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} -\int_\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}^\infty e^{-y^2} \, dy \right)\\
& \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(1+\epsilon)}} \left (\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} -e^{-n(1+\epsilon)} \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\right) 
\end{align}
$$
which implies
$$ \tag{**}
 \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n J_n \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon}} \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}  \, .
$$

Finally, $(*)$ and $(**)$ hold for all $\epsilon > 0$, and that proves
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n J_n =  \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}  \, .
$$

Comment: Wow！How wonderful it is！Thank you for your answer!It helps me a lot!I understand!You are a kind and clever person！

Comment: Did you try to get a closed form for the antiderivative using Maxima ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, I did not.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-x^2+x^3)^n\to 0 $, except for $x\to 0$. Thus, as $n\to \infty$

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2+x^3)^ndx 
\to \int_0^1 e^{-nx^2}dx \to \int_0^\infty e^{-nx^2}dx
=\frac12 \sqrt{\frac\pi n}
$$
(Disclaimer: the rigor may be improved.)

**Edit**: For completeness (per @Daniel Schepler’s comment), shown below is the higher order contribution as $x\to 1$. Let $x=1-y$. Similarly

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2+x^3)^ndx = \int_0^1 (1-y+2y^2-y^3)^ndy\\
\to \int_0^1 e^{-n y}dy \to \int_0^\infty e^{-ny}dx
=\frac1n \ll O(\frac1{\sqrt n})
$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution!But I can't follow your thinking.Why $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2+x^3)^ndx\sim \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx^2}dx$,I don't understand.Is it taylor expansion
？

Comment: @IsolYu - It is Taylor $1-x^2 \to e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Ok！Thank you for your answer!Your answer is amazing!It will take my some time to understand your answer and use your step to prove this problem!Your answer is greatly appreciated!Thank you!

Comment: From the graph of $1-x^2+x^3$, you should also consider the behavior near $x=1$ where the base of the exponent is also near 1.  However, at that point, the derivative is 1, so that part contributes a term of order $\Theta(1/n)$...

Comment: This approach can be made rigorous using the [saddle point method](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/saddle.pdf)

Comment: Can you teach me how to  prove $\int_0^1 (1-x^2+x^3)^ndx \to \int_0^1 e^{-nx^2}dx$,I still have no idea how to prove that with rigorous proof.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - You’re right. $x\to 1$ ought to be ruled out.

Comment: @Quanto Could you elaborate on your argument in the edit? One can say that it is problematic when $y$ is close to $1$, just like in the original case with $x$ being close to $0$. You would first need to cut of the original integral somewhere between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Gary - Right, $y$ handles $x\to 1$ exclusively, supplementing the initial answer

Answer (score 3):

*Alternative solution*:

Clearly, we have the lower bound
$$J_n
\ge \int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^n \,\mathrm{d} x. \tag{1}$$

We also have the upper bound
$$J_n \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt [4]n}}}\int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^n\, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{12 + 15\sqrt[4]{n}}{5n + 5}. \tag{2}$$
(The proof of (2) is given at the end.)

Note that
$$\int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^n \,\mathrm{d} x = \frac12\int_0^1 (1 - x)^n x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d} x =
\frac{\Gamma(n + 1)\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(n + 3/2)} \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}. \tag{3}$$

From (1), (2) and (3), by the squeeze theorem, we have
$$J_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}.$$

---

*Proof of* (2):

We have
\begin{align*}
 J_n &= \int_0^{1/\sqrt[4]{n}} (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^1 (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &\le \int_0^{1/\sqrt[4]{n}} \left(1 - x^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4] n}x^2\right)^n\,\mathrm{d} x
 + \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^1 (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt [4]n}}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] n}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt[4] n}}} (1 - x^2)^n\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^1 (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt [4]n}}}\int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^n\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^1 (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x.
\end{align*}

Using IBP, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{5/6}^1 (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \int_{5/6}^1 \frac{1}{3x^2 - 2x}\,\mathrm{d} \left(\frac{(1 - x^2 + x^3)^{n + 1}}{n + 1}\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{12}{5n + 5}\left(\frac{191}{216}\right)^{n + 1}
 + \frac{1}{n + 1}
 \int_{5/6}^1 \frac{(1 - x^2 + x^3)^{n + 1}(6x - 2)}{(3x^2 - 2x)^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 \le{}& \frac{1}{n + 1}
 + \frac{1}{n + 1}
 \int_{5/6}^1 \frac{6x - 2}{(3x^2 - 2x)^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 ={}& \frac{12}{5n + 5}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^{5/6} (1 - x^2 + x^3)^n\,\mathrm{d} x \\[6pt]
 \le{}& \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^{5/6} (1 - x^2 + 5x^2/6)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 ={}& \int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^{5/6} \frac{-3}{x}\,\mathrm{d} \left(\frac{(1 - x^2/6)^{n + 1}}{n + 1}\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{3 (1 - \frac{1}{6\sqrt{n}})^{n+1}\sqrt[4]{n}}{n + 1}
 - \frac{18}{5n + 5}\left(\frac{191}{216}\right)^{n+1} - \frac{1}{n + 1}\int_{1/\sqrt[4]{n}}^{5/6} \frac{3(1 - x^2/6)^{n + 1}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
 \le{}&  \frac{3\sqrt[4]{n}}{n + 1}.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Thank you very much!This helps me a lot!Thank you!

Comment: @IsolYu You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$x^3-x^2+1=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$ where
$$a=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{25}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

even if quite complex, the antiderivative exists in terms of the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.
$$I=\int \big[(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\big]^n \,dx$$
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{\big[(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\big]^{2n} }{(n+1)(a-b)^n (a-c)^n (x-a)^{n-1} }\times} $$ $$\color{blue}{F_1\left(n+1;-n,-n;n+2;\frac{x-a}{b-a},\frac{x-a}{c-a}\right)}$$ which is not easy to compute usin the analytical solutions of $(a,b,c)$; this was then done using their very accurate decimal representations.

The results for $n=10^k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k &  \sqrt{10^k}\,\,I_{10^k} \\
 0 & 0.916666667 \\
 1 & 1.518908600 \\
 2 & 1.046811249 \\
 3 & 0.902638620 \\
 4 & 0.891278324 \\
 5 & 0.887813097 \\
 6 & 0.886727429 \\
 7 & 0.886385091 \\
 8 & 0.886276907 \\
 9 & 0.886243734 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}=0.886226926$.

*Thanks to @Martin R. for reporting a probable mistake in my earlier version of this answer.*

Comment: I did some numerical integration with Maxima, and the value of $\sqrt n I_n$ *seems* to approach $\sqrt{\pi/4}$. For $n=10^8$ that value is $0.8862769311624105$. But I do not have enough experience with the used integration method to judge its precision.

Comment: @MartinR. You are right. I found a bug. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for giving me a new perspective on this problem.Thank you very much!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Good effect to verify numerically +1